# is it possible to style typescript react app with style.ts file?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript and I got a requirement that I have to style my app with a style.ts file but don't know how or either is it possible.
Need a detailed answer if it is possible and how to use it and what are the advantages of this technique.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Technically, yes, possible. Worth it? Probably not. Can you give us an example of what you expected that `style.ts` file would have?

Comment: What would make a lot more sense is to use a `style.css` file. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Well, @acdcjunior I don't have any idea how it would be implemented that's why I posted this question and never heard of such a scenario, so can't provide what it would have.

Comment: @super, I have used style.css a lot of times but I got the requirement to use style.ts as mentioned in the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do it in within typescript file, you can do as

in `style.ts` file

```
export const divStyle: {color: string, backgroundImage: string} = {
  color: 'blue',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
};
```

and then you can use it in your component as

```
import {divStyle} from './style'
function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```